# How can we get rid of scattered mobile apps positioning ?

Tags: mobile, android, ios

I'm not sure if it exists, but an "Auto apps positioning" feature in mobile OS should be introduced.

(I'm talking about iOS and Android and NOT Windows OS)

I have seen users search for their most frequently used apps in their phones. Apps that are positioned in screen 4 / screen 5 are used often, yet they remain there and users prefer scrolling screens until they find them, than moving it to a easily accessible screen.

**Reason**

1 - Either the users are lazy to move them to easily accessible screens.

2 - They do not know how to move them.

3 - They are comfortable searching for them and have adapted that way.

Users end up installing all possible apps that they think they need, but eventually don't end up using most of it. Also, they do not delete it.

In my opinion the system should intelligently sequence their apps as per their usage from most used apps to least used apps.

**Advantages**

1 - Saves User's Time.

2 - Saves Battery. (Not significantly, yet it does.)

3 - More Space - User would clearly know the screen wise categorization of the most used apps to the least used apps. This may gently prompt the user to act upon this by deleting apps which are rarely or never used, Hence making way for more space.

4 - Getting away from the scattered app positioning and remain organised.

Comment: Dont you think users will find it annoying to see their apps moved between screens?

Comment: Users should be notified about it.

Comment: this already exists http://imgur.com/deADGNh, simply scroll to the left on your iOS device to see frequently used apps

tbh its pretty useless since they are on my first page

Answer (score -1):

Imagine a world where your most frequently visited restaurant moved closer to you based on how frequently you went there. How would you find it?

This should not be the primary way apps are sorted because the real estate where apps are placed is an address, and people remember it.

If a user is so dull they don't know how to move apps around, it's even less likely that you moving them automatically "for them" is going to be anything they want or need. They're going to become infuriated in no time at all.

Those issues are big enough. But the one that might stop you in your tracks, how do you sample their use? Over a week? A month? An afternoon?

So, the answer to your question is this "We" cannot solve the scattered apps problem, and I doubt it's much of a problem. You're probably suffering from OCD transference, or some other type of annoyance at the activity of others. Let them be.